How UVCcamera solves the problem of picture delay in 4K quality
How UVCcamera solves the problem of picture delay in 4K quality.
I hope to solve this delay problem through software. Because someone else's app opens the same camera on the same device and there's no delay.
So give me a possible solution on how to solve the delay.
